# Put big query streaming NIFI processer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-nifi

I want to store some date in GCP Big Query via NIFI, I tried a lot and a lot but I have an error in NIFI [image]

I guess it's Permission error, but I'm the owner. So I don't really understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Documentation on Apache NIFI you have to use [GCPCredentialsControllerService](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-gcp-nar/1.10.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.gcp.credentials.service.GCPCredentialsControllerService/index.html) to pass your credentials of the GCP project. I recommend you to use a Service Account with the owner roles to use it as the credential file. You can see here how to [set up authentication](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) on your project.

Comment: thank you very. This is what I did now it's working perfectly